# Button text is rotated on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I created floating back to top button. On PC everything is fine however on mobile the text inside button is rotated a little and takes hell of a time to load it. What can cause this?

This is button using `materializecss`:

```
<a class="back-to-top btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green">
    <i class="material-icons">↑</i>
</a>
```

And this is css:

```
a.back-to-top {
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

And this function does scroll top:

```
var amountScrolled = 300;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > amountScrolled ) {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
$('a.back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 700);
    return false;
});
```

On PC: [image]

On Mobile: [image]

**Edit:** Just if you want to see on your own [this](https://snuspedia.firebaseapp.com/) is demo

Comment: 2 checks to do first : Did you empty you browser's cache to test this? And what does the console says ? Then, if necessary, do you have a live link to provide so I could see it ? ;)

Comment: font not loading?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added demo link :)

Comment: I will suggest you a **VERY** usefull tool for searching things like that in your local files : [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack)

Comment: **Problem confirmed**... Hold on. ;) There's **6** `italic` matches in your `style.css`. Look at this first. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check for `font-style: italic;` or `transform:skew(...)`

Yes, it is `font-style: italic;` inherited from `<i>` element.

You shall put

```
i.material-icons { font-style:normal; }
```

to suppress the slant.

Comment: In the rest of it's CSS I suppose... Can be. But then, why only on mobile? In @media rules, I would check. ;)

Comment: Your speed is impressive. ;) +1

Comment: Woww.. it did it. Thank you. But why does the label inside button appears after button appears?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp: This is strange, I agree. I would look at all `show()` / `.hide()` or `.fadeIn()` / `.fadeOut()` regarding this element. Because there is la small "lag" on first load. Then there is a strange *«fadeIn woops... I try to fadeOut... but fadein anyway»* behavior on scroll within a second or so. Good luck! Use Agent Ransack!